# In Wordpress how do you get the shortcode of an Elementor widget?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using Elementor in Wordpress and I need to get the shortcode of a Google Maps widget that I added to a page. How do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make an Elementor widget shortcode is to create a section with the element. then you will get a shortcode from Elementor.
[image]

Comment: I created the template but I don't see a shortcode column like in your screenshot

Comment: Sorry, there is no option in the free version. You have to use 3rd party plugins to get the shorcode.